# php-fpm not working on Raspberry Pie 3b+ when installing OMV5

Tags: php, raspberry-pi3, openmediavault

I'm doing a fresh install of Open Media Vault 5 on my Raspberry Pie 3B+ and ran into an issue, at the end of the installation, when I try to access my IP address on a browser I got the nginx default page.

Tried to check monit service -> runs but logs some errors about php-fpm saying php is not running.

Then I tried to check php7.3-fpm status and it appears it's not running because the service failed (code=killed, signal=ILL)

Tried to reinstall php and restart, doesn't work.

Any idea what to do or what to try to fix php-fpm?

Thx guys!

php status output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status php7.3-fpm
● php7.3-fpm.service - The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.3-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2020-05-13 04:39:28 BST; 1min 5s ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm7.3(8)
  Process: 5999 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.3 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=killed, signal=ILL)
 Main PID: 5999 (code=killed, signal=ILL)

May 13 04:39:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager...
May 13 04:39:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: php7.3-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
May 13 04:39:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: php7.3-fpm.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
May 13 04:39:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

journalctl -xe output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -xe
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/interface-lo/if_errors.rrd, [1589341091:0:0], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/run/rrdcac
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/interface-lo/if_octets.rrd, [1589341091:11280:11280], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/ru
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/interface-lo/if_dropped.rrd, [1589341091:0:0], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/run/rrdca
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/interface-eth0/if_packets.rrd, [1589341091:17154:540], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/r
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/interface-eth0/if_octets.rrd, [1589341091:895683:68830], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/interface-eth0/if_dropped.rrd, [1589341091:0:0], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/run/rrd
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/memory/memory-used.rrd, [1589341091:57155584.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/ru
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/interface-eth0/if_errors.rrd, [1589341091:0:0], 1) failed:  (status=-1)
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/memory/memory-buffered.rrd, [1589341091:24563712.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/load/load.rrd, [1589341091:0.200000:0.440000:0.550000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/memory/memory-cached.rrd, [1589341091:148512768.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/memory/memory-free.rrd, [1589341091:200642560.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/r
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/memory/memory-slab_unrecl.rrd, [1589341091:8491008.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@un
May 13 04:38:10 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/memory/memory-slab_recl.rrd, [1589341091:14450688.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@uni
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/uptime/uptime.rrd, [1589341092:1283.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/run/rrdcach
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/queue_length.rrd, [1589341092:0.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/run/r
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/operations-receive-flush.rrd, [1589341092:0], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/operations-receive-update.rrd, [1589341092:26551], 1) failed: rrdcached@u
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/gauge-tree_nodes.rrd, [1589341092:36.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/operations-write-updates.rrd, [1589341092:0], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/counter-journal-bytes.rrd, [1589341092:762095], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/gauge-tree_depth.rrd, [1589341092:6.000000], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/r
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/operations-write-data_sets.rrd, [1589341092:0], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: Successfully reconnected to RRDCacheD at unix:/run/rrdcached.sock
May 13 04:38:12 raspberrypi collectd[588]: rrdcached plugin: rrdc_update (/var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/rrdcached/counter-journal-rotates.rrd, [1589341092:0], 1) failed: rrdcached@unix:/r
May 13 04:38:16 raspberrypi sudo[5713]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status php7.3-fpm
May 13 04:38:16 raspberrypi sudo[5713]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
May 13 04:38:16 raspberrypi sudo[5713]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

service rrdcached status output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ service rrdcached status
● rrdcached.service - LSB: start or stop rrdcached
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rrdcached; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-05-13 04:17:39 BST; 31min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 483 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rrdcached start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rrdcached.service
           └─577 /usr/bin/rrdcached -B -F -f 3600 -w 900 -b /var/lib/rrdcached/db/ -j /var/lib/rrdcached/journal/ -p /run/rrdcached.pid -l unix:/run/rrdcached.sock

May 13 04:17:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start or stop rrdcached...
May 13 04:17:39 raspberrypi rrdcached[483]: rrdcached started.
May 13 04:17:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: start or stop rrdcached.
```

Comment: what output you get on service php status? and please post your `journalctl -xe` imediat after a service start tentative

Comment: @maxMuster, I've edited with both outputs

Comment: you have cutted the lines. are you kidding me ? I must go sleep please put the complete lines ... for example the line "php7.3-fpm.service: Failed with result '........." what result ?

Comment: Sorry for missclick, here you go

Comment: okay, ;-) update also the "php status output"

Comment: My cmd was too small and cut the copy, didn't even know it was doing that though

Comment: I wrote a more detailed post on OMV forum but never get an answer so far..  https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/32586-issue-with-omv5-on-raspberry-3b-seems-php-fpm-is-the-issue-please-save-me/

Comment: Dear friend, I been reading your post on the forum, you have cut the lines there too. Please update the postings with 100% complete lines. and then publish also :  "service rrdcached status"

Comment: Seems active, see output above

Comment: please give me "ls  /var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/"

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /var/lib/rrdcached/db/localhost/
cpu-0  df-root  interface-eth0  interface-lo  load  memory  rrdcached  uptime

Comment: we are going to fix this tomorrow, I am in Europe I need sleep. See you later I am @ecxod on telegram

Comment: Thx a lot, have a good night / bonne nuit if u located in France. See you later Master

Comment: I'm @corentinndc on telegram

Comment: @maxMuster, any news? tell when you want me to be available for troubleshooting